# How do I dispatch an action to reload the current route?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-router-redux

I'm using `React` with `React Router` and `Redux`. I want to be able to dispatch an action from a component, that ends up reloading the current route. Is this possible ?

I would use `browserHistory.push` but the problem with this is that I'd first have to know the current route inside the component, which I don't, at least not without adding some cumbersome hacks to the component.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: have you even bothered reading react-router-redux documentation? https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux - it explains exactly how you can access route information in components AND how to dispatch actions to change the route

Answer (score 4):

React-Router has a method to refresh/reload the page that you are currently.
https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/v0.13.3/modules/createRouter.js#L435-L437

```
Router.refresh()
```

You just need to call it from any part on your application. I don't think that you need to create an action for that.

Comment: This looks like it could work, thanks for the suggestion! But I'm using `import { Router } from 'react-router';` and the router version is 2.3.0 and there's no refresh method in there. Do I have to use `createRouter` instead ?

Answer (score -1):

inside a component you can use

```
this.context.router.push()
```

config before use

```
Component.contextTypes = {
    router: function () {
        return React.PropTypes.func.isRequired;
    }
};
```

Comment: this is not the preferred way to trigger route transitions when using redux - you need the route information in your store and it should update accordingly when the route changes - react-router-redux has this built in and that's why you should use ```store.dispatch(push('/foo'))``` to trigger route transitions